# Shorthand Background Property

Tags: css

What would be the shorthand background property for the below?

```
body {
    background-color:#161515;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #0c0b0c 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #0c0b0c 75%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #0c0b0c 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #0c0b0c 75%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, #0c0b0c 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #0c0b0c 75%), linear-gradient(45deg, #0c0b0c 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #0c0b0c 75%);
    background-position:0 0, 20px 20px;
    background-size:40px 40px;
}
```

My failed attempt:

```
background: #161515 linear-gradient(45deg, #0c0b0c 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #0c0b0c 75%), linear-gradient(45deg, #0c0b0c 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #0c0b0c 75%) 0 0, 20px 20px / 40px 40px;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sw5sevnt/1/

I believe it's crapping out because of the background position: 0 0, 20px 20px

Comment: Did you mean to put a space in `00` (the last line)?

Comment: Updated the failed attempt code. It still fails, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `background` shorthand, you specify all the longhands in each comma-separated value. This means your `background-position` values need to be distributed to each gradient, and the background color needs to go into the very last layer (it may appear anywhere in that layer so long as it's in the last one):

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #0c0b0c 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #0c0b0c 75%) 0 0/40px 40px,
            linear-gradient(45deg, #0c0b0c 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #0c0b0c 75%) 20px 20px/40px 40px #161515;
```

Note that since you have only one value for your `background-size` longhand, that same value needs to be repeated across both layers. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering) contains details on how layered shorthand declarations map to their respective longhands.

Note also that you will need to repeat this shorthand for the prefixed gradients, otherwise browsers that don't recognize the unprefixed gradients will ignore the *entire* shorthand declaration. Since you're dealing with prefixed gradients, I highly recommend using longhands instead so you can specify `background-image` on its own without having to worry about the other properties.